# sfdx scratch org Partner Community User license

Tags: community, salesforcedx, partner-portal, scratch-org, portal

On Our production Org we use Partner Community User license;

Now, we are working on the migration to sfdx, and when creating scratch orgs, we don't have Partner Community license:

Scratch org company information - User Licenses:
[image]

Production org company information - User Licenses:
[image]

For information, community feature is enabled in my project-scratch-def.json file, any idea how to get Partner Community User license in scratch orgs?

Thank you;

Comment: On a tangent, I'm not sure the DX development model does much for Communities, since all the metadata you can get for a Community is an inscrutable binary blob.

Comment: @CharlesT thank you, yes sfdx doesn't offer mush options for communities or portals, but for the moment, i just need a Partner Community License for my tests purposes (Need profile with this license)

Comment: Assuming no update means, no solutions. Just wanted to check.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the right solution for everyone, we have found in our organization that if you make your Scratch Org a Developer Edition org by putting `"edition": "Developer"` in your Scratch Org Definition JSON then you should have some Partner Community Licenses available.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i will try  with Developer Edition settings, but i hope find a better solution

Answer (score -1):

Use below configuration:

```
{
  "orgName": "Your Org Name",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": ["Communities", "CustomerCommunityPlusLogin", "ForceComPlatform"],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "networksEnabled":true,
      "ChatterEnabled":true
    }
  }
}
```

Replace CustomerCommunityPlusLogin with any Customer/Partner Community License name like CustomerCommunityPlus, GoldPartner, PartnerCommunityLogin etc.

Comment: This answer ist not accurate. `CustomerCommunityPlusLogin` is not a valid feature.